# Using system file checker to fix Windows 10 after experiencing slow boot-up

Tags: windows-10, system-file

I am using Windows 10 64-bit. I encountered slow bootup despite using SSD. I am wondering if there are some windows files that are corrupted. To check this, I ran the command;

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
```

Here is the result after completing the command;

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.17134.1

Image Version: 10.0.17134.619

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.
```

Does this mean my Windows 10 system has been fixed, at least with regards to windows system files? Do I still have to do anything more, say like running `sfc /scannow`?

I would like to check with the experts here that I used the command correctly.

The contents of dism.log is pasted here;

https://pastebin.com/zV21vMYs

Comment: You will have to supply the log that indicates what was fixed if anything

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. Where do I find this log?

Comment: Found it! C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log

Comment: @Ramhound, I pasted the contents of dism.log on https://pastebin.com/zV21vMYs
Question edited to show this.

Comment: Your command finished without any errors, your system, had zero files that needed repair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I still have to do anything more, say like running sfc /scannow?

The command you ran completed without any errors.  Your system didn’t have any files that were corrupt.  While you could run **sfc /scannow** it wouldn’t do anything.

*Your issue with your startup times are not caused by anything either command can resolve.*

Comment: I think I have discovered the problem. It could be loose cable connection on the motherboard. After I tighten the connection, Windows 10 booted up faster.